# Docker Container Unknown Host Error During Jenkins Build for auth issuer in a Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cucumber, bdd, wiremock

In my Spring boot application, I have integrated Cucumber acceptance tests, with a WireMock  server spun up using a docker image. The Dockerfile specifies the WireMock version, adds the WireMock JAR, and sets up the server.

So here, the Docker images for the application and WireMock server are built during the pipeline execution.The Docker containers are run as part of integration testing.
Cucumber acceptance tests are executed against the running Docker containers.

And I have created mappings to simulate the behaviour of an Auth0 server.
These mapping files are used in the mock server to simulate Auth0 behavior, providing predefined responses for requests to the OIDC configuration and JWKS endpoints during acceptance testing.

main pom file :

```
<modules>
    <module>inbound-product-adapter-app</module>
    <module>mock-server</module>
    <module>inbound-product-adapter-docker</module>
    <module>acceptance-tests</module>
</modules>
```

mock-server pom file :

```
<properties>
    <mock_server.base_uri.port>80</mock_server.base_uri.port>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.33.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-docker-image-acceptance-tests</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <name>inbound-claim-adapter:mock-server</name>
                                <build>
                                    <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/</dockerFileDir>
                                </build>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM 5487789965095.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/everyone/openjdk11
ADD target/wiremock-standalone-2.27.2.jar /app.jar
ADD mocks /mocks
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar","--port=80","--root-dir=/mocks","--global-response- templating", "--verbose", "--async-response-enabled", "true", "--no-request-journal", "--container-threads","20","--async-response-threads","20"]
```

build_and_run.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

WIREMOCK_VERSION=2.27.2
TAG=inbound-product-adapter:mock-server
mvn clean install -Ddependency-check.skip

docker build -t ${TAG} --build-arg wiremockversion=${WIREMOCK_VERSION} .

docker run -it --rm -p 127.0.0.1:8081:80 ${TAG}
```

auth0-jwks.json

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/.well-known/jwks.json"
    },
    "response": {
     "status": 200,
     "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "0"
    },
    "jsonBody":
    {
        "keys": [
            {
                "kty": "RSA",
                "n": "value1",
                "e": "AQAB",
                "alg": "RS256",
                "kid": "mockkey",
                "use": "sig"
            },
            {
                "kty": "RSA",
                "e": "AQAB",
                "use": "sig",
                "kid": "mockkey",
                "alg": "RS256",
                "n": "value2"
            }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

openid-configuration.json

```
{
  "request": {
     "method": "GET",
     "url": "/.well-known/openid-configuration"
   },
   "response": {
     "status": 200,
     "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Expires": "0"
    },
    "jsonBody":
    {
        "issuer": "http://api-mock-server",
        "jwks_uri": "http://api-mock-server/.well-known/jwks.json"
    }
  }
}
```

application.properties file :

```
auth0.issuer=http://api-mock-server
auth0.audience=inbound-product-adapter
```

AuthTokenSetup in acceptance-tests :

```
public class AuthTokenSetup {

   public static String testClient1AuthKey;

   @BeforeAll
   @Profile("local")
   public static void setUpLocal() {
      if(System.getProperty("cucumber.port") == null) {
          RestAssured.port = 8080;
          testClient1AuthKey = "Bearer value3";
      }
   }

   @BeforeAll
   @Profile("default")
   public static void setUpDefault() {
    {
        RestAssured.port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("cucumber.port", "8080"));
        testClient1AuthKey = "Bearer value4";

    }
  }
}


public class StepsDefs {

   private static final String testClient1AuthKey = AuthTokenSetup.testClient1AuthKey;
   private static RequestSpecification request;
   private static Response response;


   @Before
   public static void setUp() {
      RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("cucumber.base_uri", "http://localhost:8080/inbound-product-adapter/v1");
      request = given();
   }

   @After
   public static void resetResponse() {
      request = null;
      response = null;
   }

   @When("the client requests a claim note be posted")
   public void publishProductsRequest() throws JsonProcessingException {
      Map<String,Object> productRequest = createProductRequest();
      request.accept(APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
      request.contentType(APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
      request.body(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(productRequest));
      request.header("Authorization", testClient1AuthKey);
      response = request.post("/products");
   }
 }
```

However, it seems that Docker container is unable to resolve the host api-mock-server during startup in Jenkins pipeline.

Stacktrace :

```
12:34:24  044c2c> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: 
Factory method 'jwtDecoder' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://api-mock-server"
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
12:34:24  044c2c>   ... 79 common frames omitted
12:34:24  044c2c> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://api-mock-server"

12:34:24  044c2c> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://api-mock-server/.well-known/openid-configuration": 
api-mock-server
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888)
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868)
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:714)
12:34:24  044c2c>   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.getConfiguration(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.java:155)
12:34:24  044c2c>   ... 93 common frames omitted
12:34:24  044c2c> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api-mock-server

12:34:58  [ERROR] DOCKER> [inbound-product-adapter:mock-server] "api-mock-server": Container stopped with exit code 1 unexpectedly after 
1291 ms while waiting on url http://localhost:45983/health
12:34:58  [ERROR] DOCKER> Error occurred during container startup, shutting down...
12:34:58  [INFO] DOCKER> [inbound-product-adapter:mock-server] "api-mock-server": Stop and removed container 5abf5e126773 after 0 ms
12:34:58  [ERROR] DOCKER> I/O Error [[inbound-product-adapter:mock-server] "api-mock-server": Container stopped with exit code 1 unexpectedly 
after 1291 ms while waiting on url http://localhost:45983/health]
```